# Unable to connect External Jar in Livy

Tags: java, apache-spark, livy

We are trying to build a setup where we have a server that submits jobs of different users to the Livy server via the REST API. 
And we have submitted the jar in hdfs and calling that from livy client.

There is demo code,where it is calling json-simple jar and getting exception -

The exception is that -
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser

So,what could be the solution to handle external jars in the livy.

As we are trying to execute the following code- 
code follows-

```
try {
    LivyClient client = new LivyClientBuilder().setURI(new URI(livyUrl)).build();  
    String s="hdfs://ofss2311699:8020/user/jars/json_parsing_module.jar"; 
    client.addJar(new URI(s)).get();  
    String json_string= "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";  
    client.submit(new JsonParse(json_string)).get();  
 }  

finally {   
}
```

Comment: Is you application dependent on the `json-simple` library? If that's the case, you can add it as part of your application build process, i.e. uber/fat JAR.

Comment: yes,that we have tried,this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Then you may have to share the complete error log.

Comment: Error Log - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser